# lubuntu 12.10 bluetooth mouse disconnecting

Tags: 12.10, mouse, lubuntu, bluetooth

In Lubuntu 12.10 I use a bluetooth mouse, but it will not stay connected. I have to set it to connect as an input device and it will work fine for a little while. Sometimes it disconnects in the middle of using it; sometimes the mouse goes to sleep to save battery power and it will not reconnect after waking up. It always disconnects when I use the power button on the menu to bring up the shut down options. Often I have to reconnect, disconnect,reconnect etc until the mouse starts working again. I also get messages like ubuntu has experienced an error, if you notice problems restart the system. Is there any way to fix this besides waiting for the next version of lubuntu to come out and hoping that a fix for this is included?

Comment: Also, I tested 2 bluetooth keyboards with built in mouse functions and they do not suffer from the same problem. they both work as they should. This should confirm that it is not my bluetooth dongle that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this bug is similar to the following:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1072234

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1065157

Something I've noticed is if we switch between sessions, mouse gets back to work fine. 
Try it:

1. Make sure mouse stops to work
2. Switch to another session performing: ALT + F1
3. Then, switch back to GUI session: ALT + F7

Mouse should work again.
(try it more than once if it doesn't work...)

Comment: Sometimes suspending and returning from suspend reconnects my mouse. Switching between sessions has never worked for me.